# I told my recruiter way too much information

Tags: recruitment

I have been in contact with two potential jobs. One direct hire, and one through a recruiter. The job with direct hire offered me a position a few weeks ago, and I told them I would accept.

However, the recruiter from the other job recently called, I told him I had another offer and that I was no longer interested (he said he would try and find me more positions though). He also kept prying about my current offer, and I gave away way too much information! I just graduated college, and this was my first experience dealing with this type of thing.

What do I do? I'm nervous I am going to lose my new job.

Comment: What exactly do you think the recruiter will do here? Why / how do you think you'll lose the other job by simply telling someone about it?

Comment: I heard that recruiters could sabotage you to get you to sing with them... so that they can make their commission/ benefit from brining a new employee on board.

Comment: I've never heard a recruiter doing that. As @Myles says, it's more likely they're just trying to extract information from you to help with their future placements. Just be careful not to share more information that you're comfortable with in the future and good luck in your new job.

Comment: This has happened to me quite a bit. Reveal the information you want to and am legally able to disclose. Generally, recruiter are just gathering more information to stay competitive with other companies. I don't see how the recruiter could or would even care to jeopardize your current offer.

Comment: I hope you learned your lesson. Many agents work for themselves and the client, never for the candidate. Tell them as little as possible. Always deny you have any other jobs in the pipeline. Never tell them about other interviews you have had or are coming up. And never give them the names of any of your business contacts. I do, however, agree with the consensus that you would need to be very unlucky for this to unwind for you.

Answer (score 13):

Congratulations on your first job out of college!

What's done is done.  It's possible that the recruiter would try to sour the deal for you however that's very unlikely.  Much more likely is the recruiter is trying to get business intelligence from you to improve on their own business (names of hiring manager, information on hiring process, etc).  Any information about hiring in your new company could give him a competitive edge over other recruiters.  This is probably the driver behind his behavior.

Comment: I agree with Myles assessment. It's very unlikely for recruiters to try to sabotage your current offer. If anything, he would just try to gauge your compensation and perhaps reach out to you 6 -12 months from now for possible better opportunities. These recruiters only make money if they staff people to their clients. The less bridges they burn, the more chance to make money for them.

Comment: Trying to badmouth you to your new employer would be very likely to backfire. If a company hears bad things from a different recruiter, they will first ask either you or the recruiter that brought you to the company. Then the lies will be found out. Then your company, and your own recruiter, will have a serious talk with that recruiter's company.